# CFDataRef and Pixel Data for iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgimageref, cfdata

I am trying to access the raw pixels of an image, but I keep running into a problem that got me really stuck. I am pretty new to iPhone programming so it might be something really simple...

Here is the class I have, it uses a `CGImageRef` from an image and looks at the individual pixels. Here is my code

The header file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>


@interface GraphingView : UIControl 
{
@private
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;    
    CGImageRef pixelData;
}

@property(assign) CGImageRef pixelData;
@end
```

And my implementation file:

```
#import "GraphingView.h"
#import "iSpectrumViewController.h"

@implementation GraphingView

@synthesize pixelData;
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // set up a rounded border
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];

    // clear the view's background color so that our background
    // fits within the rounded border
    CGColorRef backgroundColor = [self.backgroundColor CGColor];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    layer.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;


    shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];      

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

}

- (void)updateGraph
{
    // This is where my problem is:
     // Whenever the next line is executed the application stops working. It works fine in the setPixelData
     // down below.
    CFDataRef pixelRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(pixelData));
    CFIndex byteSize = CFDataGetLength(pixelRef);
    int intByteSize = (int) byteSize;
    NSLog(@"Number of Bytes contained %i",intByteSize);

     //Then get a pointer to the data so the information can be accessed
    const UInt8 *pixelPtr = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelRef);


    // Do some drawing here using the data obtained from the image...

    [shapeLayer setPath:path];
    [shapeLayer setNeedsDisplay];
    CFRelease(path);    
}

-(void)setPixelData:(CGImageRef)pixelImage
{
     //This code takes the CGImage from my image and copies it to the pixelData CGImageRef defined in the header file


    //This gets the CFDataRef from the CGImage so the pixel information is available
    CFDataRef PixelCopy = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(pixelImage));
    CFIndex byteSize = CFDataGetLength(PixelCopy);
    int intByteSize = (int) byteSize;
    NSLog(@"Number of Bytes contained %i",intByteSize);

    pixelData = CGImageCreateCopy(pixelImage);
    [self updateGraph];

}
@end
```

The problem I have is:

The function `setPixelData` gets the `CGImageRef` image and copies it to `pixelData`. Then, up in the `(void) updateGraph` method, I use the `CGImageRef pixelData` and create a `CFDataRef` to get the raw pixel data. However, there is something wrong. Because when I use the `CFDataGetLength` method using the `CFDataRef pixelRef` as input I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when the program is run. What confuses me is that when I then put the same two lines of code in the `(void) setPixelData` function  (shown in the code above) and comment out the code in `updateGraph` then the program runs perfectly fine.

Any ideas of what could be causing this error,  and how to eliminate it?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Why not use `CGImageGetData()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... I found it,

The reason it didn't work was because I had two setter methods (one of them is not shown in the code). That one always ran before the `setPixelData` function, so `PixelData CGImageRef` was never set, therefore, `CFDataRef` did not exist, giving the memory error.